# Эффект размытия фона / Эффект матового стекла — CSS

Tags: css, веб-дизайн

как сделать эффект размытия фона или эффект матового стекла как в iOS? я понимаю, что можно добавить фильтр на картинку.. но как мне добавить этот фильтр на отдельный слой и наложить этот слой поверх n'ое количество картинок??

Comment: Вы про [blur эффект](http://demosthenes.info/blog/534/Cross-browser-Image-Blur-with-CSS)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Используйте `filter: blur(5px);`, ниже пример.

```css
img {
    width: 300px;
}

.blur {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
     -moz-filter: blur(5px);
       -o-filter: blur(5px);
      -ms-filter: blur(5px);
          filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="http://www.subaruwrx.net/images/2006-sti-rb320-lg1.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="blur">
    <img src="http://www.subaruwrx.net/images/2006-sti-rb320-lg1.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: а не нельзя к отдельному слою применить этот эффект? потом чтобы ложить его поверх элементов??

Comment: применяйте класс к любому нужному слою, как видите у меня в коде внутри слоя находится изображение и их может быть несколько, как слоёв так и изображений внутри слоя