# Hover эффект для изображений

Tags: css, hover

[image: hover]

Подскажите, как оформить вот такой вот эффект при наведении на картинку? Какими средствами?
Ну размытие через blur можно сделать. Я просто не могу понять как мне поверх всего этого стрелки примастырить.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Эффект размытия фона / Эффект матового стекла — CSS](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/426332/%d0%ad%d1%84%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ad%d1%84%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0-css)

Comment: а в чём конкретно у вас возникли трудности? С эффектом размытия или с наведением мыши?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерно всё так делается

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 360px;
}

.parent-child {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #eee;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.parent-child-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/370ca5f8dbccb9352ae29c89dddfff0e?s=100&d=identicon&r=PG);
  transition: all 0.5s;
  filter: blur(0px);
}
.parent-child:hover .parent-child-image {filter: blur(3px);}

.parent-child-block {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.parent-child:hover .parent-child-block {opacity: 1}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="parent-child">
    <div class="parent-child-image"></div>
    <div class="parent-child-block">Тут стрелки</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent-child">
    <div class="parent-child-image"></div>
    <div class="parent-child-block">Тут стрелки</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent-child">
    <div class="parent-child-image"></div>
    <div class="parent-child-block">Тут стрелки</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent-child">
    <div class="parent-child-image"></div>
    <div class="parent-child-block">Тут стрелки</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent-child">
    <div class="parent-child-image"></div>
    <div class="parent-child-block">Тут стрелки</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent-child">
    <div class="parent-child-image"></div>
    <div class="parent-child-block">Тут стрелки</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent-child">
    <div class="parent-child-image"></div>
    <div class="parent-child-block">Тут стрелки</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent-child">
    <div class="parent-child-image"></div>
    <div class="parent-child-block">Тут стрелки</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent-child">
    <div class="parent-child-image"></div>
    <div class="parent-child-block">Тут стрелки</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.b-pict {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
}

.b-pict>img {
  transition: .3s;
}

.b-pict:hover>img {
  filter: blur(5px);
}

.b-pict-arrow {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .3s;
  position: absolute;
}

.b-pict-arrow:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
}

.b-pict-arrow-top,
.b-pict-arrow-bottom {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -4px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #555;
}

.b-pict-arrow-top {
  top: 25%;
}

.b-pict-arrow-bottom {
  bottom: 25%;
}

.b-pict-arrow-top:after,
.b-pict-arrow-bottom:after {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.b-pict-arrow-top:after {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-width: 0 10px 20px 10px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #555 transparent;
}

.b-pict-arrow-bottom:after {
  top: 100%;
  border-width: 20px 10px 0 10px;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.b-pict-arrow-left,
.b-pict-arrow-right {
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -4px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #555;
}

.b-pict-arrow-left {
  left: 25%;
}

.b-pict-arrow-right {
  right: 25%;
}

.b-pict-arrow-left:after,
.b-pict-arrow-right:after {
  top: 50%;
}

.b-pict-arrow-left:after {
  right: 100%;
  margin-top: -10px;
  border-width: 10px 20px 10px 0;
  border-color: transparent #555 transparent transparent;
}

.b-pict-arrow-right:after {
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -10px;
  border-width: 10px 0 10px 20px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #555;
}

.b-pict:hover .b-pict-arrow {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="b-pict">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  <span class="b-pict-arrow b-pict-arrow-top"></span>
  <span class="b-pict-arrow b-pict-arrow-bottom"></span>
  <span class="b-pict-arrow b-pict-arrow-left"></span>
  <span class="b-pict-arrow b-pict-arrow-right"></span>
</div>
```